# Filter csv rows with multiple conditions

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Hi I want to filter out rows whose 2nd column (Hex) has value `80` or `81` and filter out rows whose 2nd column is `0`  only if its below the row which has `81` in the second column:

**sample.csv :**

```
Delta,Hex,Type,Time

0,81,DTE,10 pm
1,0,DTE,10 pm
0,01,DTE,10 pm
1,1c,DTE,9 pm
1,0,DTE,10 pm
0,1d,DTE,10 pm
1,0,DTE,10 pm
```

So here's the script which I wrote which filters out rows with values `80` `81` and `0` in the second column(Hex).

**Script.py:**

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:

  rows=csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=None,restkey=None,restval=None,dialect='excel',delimiter=",")

  filtered_rows=filter(lambda p:'80' != p['Hex'] and '81' != p['Hex'] and '0' != p['Hex'], rows)

  for i in filtered_rows :

    print (i['Hex'])
```

So it filters out all the rows which has `0` in their second column.

**Current output with the above script:**

```
01
1c
1d
```

But I dont want to filter the row which has `0` in the second column if its not below the row which has `81` in the second column:

**Expected output :**

```
01
1c
0
1d
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a non-current state, the 0 condition, you should filter the list iterating it, not with lambda

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
...     rows=csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=None,restkey=None,restval=None,dialect='excel',delimiter=",")
...     filtered_rows=[]
...     previous_flag=False
...     for item in rows:
...         if item['Hex'] not in ['81','80'] and not (previous_flag and  item['Hex'] == '0'):
...             filtered_rows.append(item)
...         previous_flag = item['Hex'] == '81'
...     for i in filtered_rows :
...         print (i['Hex'])
... 
01
1c
0
1d
0
```

Comment: This script will work only if `81` occurs every time after `0` but that's not the case. If 6th row is `0,1d,DTE,10 pm` it will not append the 5th row which it should.

Comment: could you edit your question with new data and the desired result?